# How to link my Mojang account with my Microsoft account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, microsoft

When I try to log into Minecraft, I am prevented and forced to click on a link to migrate my Mojang account to my Microsoft account, but after doing that my accounts aren't linked, and when I log into the Microsoft account in Minecraft (as if I didn't pay), I am presented with a "Play Demo" button (as though I didn't pay). When I try to go through the process again, the page simply redirects me to this page:

Minecraft.net/en-us/msaprofile

There is nothing on that page that offers any information whatsoever about migrating the account.  There is no information of any sort that I have found Googling.  Only Microsoft can screw up something so colossally.  How do I link my Mojang account to my Microsoft account, so I can use the software that I paid for?

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/389928/110875) is not helpful because I do remember my Minecraft/Mojang account info.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem and was confused.

I solved it by, logging back into my Mojang account on the client and clicking migrate a second time. Now you log into that newly created Microsoft account from the previous session, and it should work.