# How to recover my old Minecraft account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to recover my old Minecraft account. I used to play on that account in 2014-2015. All that I know is that the username is r41nco. Is there any chance to recover it?

Comment: This sounds like something for Mojang support, not Arqade

Comment: ... but apparently people ask it enough times on Arqade that there's a canonical for it - Possible duplicate of [How can I recover my account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278757/how-can-i-recover-my-account)

Comment: Oops, right, I can close questions on my own… Maybe I should take that a bit more seriously than just one out of five votes. :D I've found a better question that's about this exactly, so I'll reopen and close differently now.

Comment: Oh, I can't do that, oh no! Umm, can someone else please vote to close as duplicate of this? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/389928/171580

Answer (score -1):

I would do one of the following:

1. Get a new account (Hopefully you won't need to)
2. Contact support https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/requests/new

   When contacting support, try to get proof of owning the account.
3. Try to reset the password via email. However, if this is an older account that hasn't migrated then this may not be possible.

Good luck!

Comment: @pppery I want to help them?